# Pytorch - batches doesn't update

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

I was training my model but some issues occurred. 
The dataloader was supposed to update batches but instead I got this:

#### Output

- [0,     0] loss: 0.009
- [1,     0] loss: 0.009
- [2,     0] loss: 0.009
- [3,     0] loss: 0.009
- [4,     0] loss: 0.009
- [5,     0] loss: 0.009
- [6,     0] loss: 0.009
- [7,     0] loss: 0.009
- [8,     0] loss: 0.009
- [9,     0] loss: 0.009

Anyone know what's wrong? My codes are as below

### DataLoader

```
class MSourceDataSet(Dataset):

    def __init__(self, clean_dir, mix_dir, clean_label_dir, mix_label_dir):

        with open(clean_dir + 'clean1.json') as f:
            clean0 = torch.Tensor(json.load(f))

        with open(mix_dir + 'mix1.json') as f:
            mix0 = torch.Tensor(json.load(f))

        with open(clean_label_dir + 'clean_label1.json') as f:
            clean_label0 = torch.Tensor(json.load(f))


        with open(mix_label_dir + 'mix_label1.json') as f:
            mix_label0 = torch.Tensor(json.load(f))


        self.spec = torch.cat([clean0, mix0], 0)
        self.label = torch.cat([clean_label0, mix_label0], 0)

    def __len__(self):
        return self.spec.shape[0]


    def __getitem__(self, index): 

        spec = self.spec[index]
        label = self.label[index]
        return spec, label

trainset = MSourceDataSet(clean_dir, mix_dir, clean_label_dir, mix_label_dir)

trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset = trainset,
                                                batch_size = 4,
                                                shuffle = True)

# testloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset = testset,
#                                                batch_size = 4,
#                                                shuffle = True)
```

### Training

```
model.train()

for epoch in range(10):
    running_loss = 0

    for i, data in enumerate(trainloader, 0):

        inputs, labels = data

        optimizer.zero_grad()

        outputs = model(inputs)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        running_loss += loss.item()
        if i % 1000 == 0:
            print ('[%d, %5d] loss: %.3f' % (epoch, i, running_loss/ 1000))
            running_loss = 0

torch.save(model, 'FeatureNet.pkl')
```

Comment: why do you think the problem is in the dataloader? it could be that your model does not improve: learning rate is too low / init state of weights is such that no meaningful gradients exists... try to debug and inspect `data`

Comment: @Shai The main reason is the printed result of epoch and batch. The dataloader was set to batch_size = 4, and the `len` was 1100. However the `batch` in the printed results were not updated

Comment: as far as I can tell you are printing every 1000 iterations, if  your dataset `len` is 1100 and `batch_size` is 4 it means you only have 1100/4 = 275 iterations per epoch, thus you only print when `i=0`. try and print every 100 iterations and see if it changes.

Comment: @Shai wow thanks! I think I missed this obvious point. I will check that and then examine the other elements you mentioned